# Keeping a connection alive: Large Timeout vs Keepalive

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using WCF with Pipes in a C# .NET application. I don't want connections to be closed because of inactivity. Now, there are two options I have: Set the Timeouts very high/infinite or send keepalive messages.

What would be the better option for this and why? Personally I'd say infinite Timeouts, but I'm not sure.